# NuSOAP on XAMPP with PHP5: failed to open stream

Tags: xampp, nusoap, php4, php

Hey guys, I have a problem (again). This time I am trying to use NuSoap w/ XAMPP 1.7.1 which includes PHP5 and MySQL ... I wrote a soap-client:

```
<?php
// Pull in the NuSOAP code
require_once('nusoap.php');
// Create the client instance
$client = new soapclient('http://localhost/mysql/helloworld2.php');
// Check for an error
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    // Display the error
    echo '<p><b>Constructor error: ' . $err . '</b></p>';
    // At this point, you know the call that follows will fail
}
// Call the SOAP method
$result = $client->call('hello', array('name' => 'Doro'));
// Check for a fault
if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<p><b>Fault: ';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</b></p>';
} else {
    // Check for errors
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        // Display the error
        echo '<p><b>Error: ' . $err . '</b></p>';
    } else {
        // Display the result
        print_r($result);
    }
}

?>
```

and my soap-server:

```
   // Enable debugging *before* creating server instance
   $debug = 1;
   // Create the server instance
   $server = new soap_server;
   // Register the method to expose
   $server->register('hello');

   // Define the method as a PHP function
   function hello($name) {

$dbhost = 'blah';
$dbuser = 'blub';
$dbpass = 'booboo';
try{
       $conn = MYSQL_CONNECT($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) 
           or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

    if( !$conn ){
        return 'Hello, '.$name.' ...  too bad, I cannot connect to the db!';
    }
    else{
        $dbname = 'soaperina';
        MYSQL_SELECT_DB($dbname) or die('Error connecting to '.dbname);

        $queryres = @mysql_db_query(
                          'response',
                          'SELECT * FROM farben');

                    return 'RESPONSE: <br>';

                   while( $arr = mysql_fetch_array( $queryres ) ){
                         return $arr["ID"]." - ".$arr["Farben"]." - ".$arr["Rating"]."<br>";
                   }
            }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
                 return 'Sorry, '.$name.', but that did not work at all!';
        }


   }
   // Use the request to (try to) invoke the service
   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
   $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

I know that PHP works, the Apache works, MySQL works ... it also works together, but when I try to make it work with NuSOAP it does not work. I get following:

> Warning:
>   SoapClient::SoapClient(http://localhost/mysql/helloworld2.php)
>   [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to
>   open stream: Ein Verbindungsversuch
>   ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle
>   nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht
>   richtig reagiert hat, oder die
>   hergestellte Verbindung war
>   fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host
>   nicht reagiert hat. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql\helloworld2client.php
>   on line 6
>
> Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient()
>   [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning :
>   failed to load external entity
>   "http://localhost/mysql/helloworld2.php"
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql\helloworld2client.php
>   on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of
>   60 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql\helloworld2client.php
>   on line 41

I have no idea what that is supposed to mean. I hope ya'll can help!!! Thnx in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to give an answer to my own question: nusoap has a problem with php5 ... there are some answers and some solutions on the net (not many), but they didn't work with me. I downgraded to php4 and it works fine ...

Answer (score 2):

I used NuSOAP version 1.7.3 with PHP5. In this NuSOAP 1.7.3, soapclient class renamed by nu_soapclient.

You can try this:

```
$client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/mysql/helloworld2.php');
```